# Angular UI Router: Dedicated UI-View

Tags: angular-ui-router

I am wondering if it is possible to have two ui-views one one site: both are child of the parent state. I want first ui-view to be dedicated to the first child, and second to the second one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely understand the question, but ui-views can be nested in any way to form a tree structure. This is done using the dot notation for states.

```
state1.state2
state1.state3
```

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view

If you want to keep two views within the same state, you can use the `ui-view` `name` attribute to handle that. The linked page explains how toward the bottom.

From the linked page:

Really though, you'll use views to set up multiple views:

```
<div ui-view></div>
<div ui-view="chart"></div> 
<div ui-view="data"></div>
```

And the JS:

```
$stateProvider.state("home", {
  views: {
    "": {
      template: "<h1>HELLO!</h1>"
    },
    "chart": {
      template: "<chart_thing/>"
    },
    "data": {
      template: "<data_thing/>"
    }
  }    
})
```

It's also worth mentioning that each view object here can have its own controller.

Information from comment stream:

The answer is no, there's no way to have two `ui-view`s for separate sub-states. You would have to create one `ui-view` with two separate states under it, which would still only allow one to be shown at a time. I really think you're looking for two views in the same state, but without an example all I can do is guess.

Comment: I was wondering if I can assign one <ui-view></ui-view> to a specific child of a state.

Comment: I see. Check out the next to last example at the linked page.

Comment: Hmm.. I think this is not exactly it. It referes to the views of the same state, not to the child's of that state.

Comment: I'm confused. A state would be the state of the application, potentially nested as a state of being. To have two states "viewable" at the same level at the same time is unintuitive. Maybe an example of your use case would help?

Comment: After re-reading the question, maybe I understand now. The answer is no, there's no way to have two `ui-view`s for separate sub-states. You would have to create one `ui-view` with two separate states under it, which would still only allow one to be shown at a time. I really think you're looking for two views in the same state, but without an example all I can do is guess.

Comment: Thanks! If thats not a problem, it would be great if you could edit answer, and include what you have mentioned here :)